PhD Reapplication
I had applied for a PhD last year but couldn't get in. The professor who I wanted to work under told me that he really liked my project and encouraged me to reapply this year. I do have plans to reapply to this university and to a few others, where I had reached out to professors whose areas of interest align with mine but since I did not have the desired level of language training, they insisted that I undergo the said training and then apply. I want to pursue a PhD in Asian studies where candidates are required to have at least college second year level training before joining a PhD course. Now I am through with the language training, but I was wondering if I should be reaching out to the same professors I reached out to last year (who were actually interested in my project but also asked me to first get up to the required language level) with the same project or should also modify my project a bit, and add further questions, etc.? Is it okay to reach out to them with the same set of questions that I reached out to them with earlier or am I expected to have worked further on my project along with working on the language?

East Asian Study programs are very competitive and often require two East Asian language (a primary and a secondary) at a very high level (my first Ph.D. was in Japanese Studies). If the professors liked your proposal I suggest reaching out to them, reminding them about the previous conversation and concentrating on letting them know how you progressed in your language studies (which is what they asked you to do).
I would not advise asking the exact same thing you asked before, instead you can remind them about what you asked and what they said and ask if there were any changes in that regard. It's how you phrase it.

What you suggest seems reasonable. Remind them of the previous contact and that your questions are the same if you think it necessary. They won't have remembered some or all of that, but it might be good to mention it.
Focus, of course, on your language studies since you last contacted them. But your approach seems sound. Good luck.

Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer. So is it okay to approach them with the same questions? Is that not going to reflect badly on my ability to conduct research since I had the same set of questions a year ago?

You have been focusing on the language.
